# Installing R on RHEL 6 R-java-devel requires java-devel

Tags: java, r

All - trying to get R installed on RHEL 6.

I've resolved all the basic R dependencies and stuck on: 
*R-java-devel requires  java-devel*.

#### Here is the java on the system

```
[anyuser ~]$ rpm -qa |grep java

java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.45-2.4.3.3.el6.x86_64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45-2.4.3.3.el6.x86_64


[anyuser ~]$ alternatives --config java

There are 3 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
   1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.5.0-gcj/bin/java
   2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
*+ 3           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java

[anyuser ~]$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_45

[anyuser ~]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.3.3.el6-x86_64 u45-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

To me it looks like java and jdk is correct, but this wont let me install r using yum

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue on CentOS 6.5 (2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64). I 've managed to bypass the java-devel dependency problem and can install a working copy of R. I'd be worried about problems further down the line though - so I'm hoping somebody has a proper fix.

Steps:

1. install open JDK : 
   yum install --enablerepo=updates java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64
2. download R rpms : 
   yumdownloader --resolve --archlist=x86_64 --enablerepo=epel R.x86_64
3. install everything except R-java :
   yum install R-* --skip-broken
4. force install R-java-devel rpm :
   rpm -Uvh --force --nodeps R-java-devel-3.1.2-1.el6.x86_64
5. re-run R install and make sure it completes :
   yum install R-*

Comment: Interesting, and thanks for the reply. In my case i found R was already installed and I did not know it! So double check by issuing R at a command prompt. Yum nor rpm -qa |grep R returned anything - most likely R was installed from source...